# How do you say "The 10 most spoken languages in the world" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

Would it be:

> 世界中１０の最も話し言語

or

> 世界で１０最も話されて言語

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with 話されている "are spoken".

We'll use that as a relative clause to modify 言語 "language":

> 話されている言語
>   *languages that are spoken*

And we'll add 最も "most":

> 最も話されている言語
>   *languages that are spoken the most*
>   = the *[most spoken] languages*

And 世界で to make the scope "in the world":

> 世界で最も話されている言語
>   *the most spoken languages in the world*

Last, we insert １０の to say *how many* of the most spoken languages:

> 世界で最も話されている１０の言語
>   *the ten most spoken languages in the world*

Comment: I just loved the way you constructed the sentence block by block! You would make a great teacher (unless you already are lol)

Comment: You broke that down so well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

I would probably say one of

```
話者数上位１０言語
話者数による世界トップ１０言語
世界で最も話されている言語の上位１０言語
```